# I cant get my logo to appear on the navbar

Tags: html, django-templates, bootstrap-4

[This is what I'm getting right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdyZ3.png) For some reason when I try to get my navbar logo to appear, instead of the logo, I get some type of picture icon. Here is my code:

```
`<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="/images/logo.png">Imito</a>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topNavBar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Hot</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">New</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Top</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>`
```

Comment: What's the css look like?

Comment: are you getting a 404 error for the image file? If not, you may want to verify the image mode is 'RGB Color' not 'CMYK Color'

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that I needed to do something with CSS when adding a logo. When I look at the webpage it doesn't give me an error, but there is an icon that looks like a landscape in place of the logo.

Comment: can you attach at least a screenshot of the page?

Comment: yeah I just added a picture

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your program is unable to locate the picture in the specified path or it cannot access the specified path. My advice is to place the logo in the same folder as the html code and just use `<img src = "logo.png">`

It should definitely work then.

Answer (score 0):

Can’t comment so had to use an answer, have you checked the console to see if it returns a 404 for the image. It sounds like the file you specified cannot be found?